# Collider luminosity basics

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

In a collider experiment, the Luminosity is defined as the proportionality factor between the interaction rate and the interaction cross section $dN/dt = L\times\sigma$, with units of $cm^{-2}s^{-1}$. I was curious to see how this quantity is related to the flux of incoming particles since it has the same units as the flux. Doing some research I came across this [paper](https://cds.cern.ch/record/941318/) that states:

> A priori the two beams have different
> distribution functions and a different number of particles in the beams.
> The overlap integral which is proportional to the luminosity ($L$) we can then write as:
> $$ L ∝ K ·\int\int\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ \rho_{1}(x, y, s, −s_0) \rho_2(x, y, s, s_0) dxdydsds_0
> $$
> where $\rho_{1,2}$ are the ) are the time-dependent beam density distribution functions. We assume, that the two bunches meet at $s_0 = 0$. Because the beams are moving against each other, we have to multiply this expression with a kinematic factor $K$

here they used $s_0 = ct$ as a "time" coordinate. I believe in this equation is established the relation between the fluxes of the two beams but it seems to have probability theory too. However, I do not get the basic reasoning that leads to this equation. Could someone explain me?

Answer (score 0):

It is related to the density distribution and the kinematic factor $K$. For head-on collision we have $K = 2v$ with $v$ the beam velocity. Now the particle flux is (as seen by the other beam):

$$
\Phi_{1, 2}(x, y, s, s_0) = 2v\cdot\rho_{1,2}(x, y, s, \pm s_0)
$$

It depends on the observer's position $(x, y, s)$ as well as how far the beam/bunch is away ($s_0$).

Following the paper a bit further, they calculate the luminosity for two Gaussian beam profiles ([section 4](https://cds.cern.ch/record/941318/files/p361.pdf#page=4)). It turns out to be:

$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{N_1 N_2 f N_b}{4\pi\sigma_x\sigma_y}
$$

Now the *average* particle flux is (averaged over one revolution period as well as the transverse dimensions), as seen by the other beam:

$$
\phi_{1,2} = \frac{N_{1,2}fN_b}{4\pi\sigma_x\sigma_y}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is that the probability of a particle to collide with an incoming distributions will *increase* if it goes deeper or stays longer within the distribution. The overlap integral only quantifies this increment, you can see it as purely geometrical if you want.

The actual probabilistic part of a collision to take place, is factored out into the cross section, which you need if you want to compute the average number of a particular events per bunch crossing (or unit time).

For example if you want to get the total number of collision produced by the LHC over some period of time T you will do:

$$N_\text{evt}=\int_\text{T} \mathcal L(t) \, \sigma_\text{pp} \, d\text{t} = \bar{\mathcal L}\, \sigma_\text{pp}\,T$$
where $\sigma_\text{pp}$ is the total proton-proton cross section at the given energy.